# Can buying ads improve the SEO of the my page?

Tags: seo, advertising

I have a page which I would like to ranking Google for a specific keyword.  This is a not the home page. This is a sub-page. Traffic is very high on this keyword and there is fierce competition for it.

If paid links and guest posts are very bad for SEO then what is the alternative method? Is buying ads the best way to improve SEO of  my sub-page?  (Meaning directing internet users to the site with ads.)

Comment: See [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that increases your web presence is likely to positively impact your SEO. Ads increase your brand awareness. If these ads causes users to share your content on social media, organically link to your page, talk about about your brand, or search for your company on Google you SERP position is likely to go up.

But you shouldn't expect the links pointing to your site from ads to increase your rankings. Many ads add the rel="nofollow" tag so the backlink won't count. And Google has said that buying backlinks is a big no no. If you buy an ad to your site with a paid for backlink it's possible that you may get penalized for it if Google finds out. This is just something you have to think about.

As for advertising in general though, yes it will help your brand. And anything that helps your brand that is in line with Google Webmaster Guidelines is likely to increase your rankings.

Comment: I agree ads may help indirectly a little bit.  However,  the return on investment from any SEO benefit would be tiny.   If you spend $100 in ads, you might expect $0.05 in SEO benefit from that.  It is almost negligible.   It is almost always more effective for SEO to spend your money improving your site or targeting influencers than general advertising.    In the past I have seen some companies with giant advertising budgets criticize Google for not making "verified ad budget" a direct ranking factor.  They argue the amount of money spend on advertising would be a good quality signal.